# Django: passing ChoiceField choices to form's `__init__()` as positional argument causes AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to pass an argument from views.py to forms.py to create a `ChoiceField` with `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget but the rendering fails.

> Exception Type: AttributeError  Exception Value: 'list' object has no
>   attribute 'get'.

Could you please take a look below and throw some light as to what I am doing wrong :(

Thanks for your help in advance.

forms.py:

```
class TestSubmitForm(forms.Form):
    tests = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.testList = args[0]
        super(TestSubmitForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['tests'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['tests'].choices = self.testList
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    tc_obj_form = [("","1"),("","2"),("",3")]
    tests = TestSubmitForm(tc_obj_form)
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'tests':tests})
```

index.html

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <table >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ tests }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback: File "/local/User/demo/web/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/local/User/demo/web/apps/Lcloud/views.py" in index
  94.           return render(request, 'Lcloud/index.html',
  ...
  135.         return self.as_table() File "/local/User/demo/web/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_table
  257.             errors_on_separate_row=False) File "/local/User/demo/web/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  181.         top_errors = self.non_field_errors()  # Errors that should be displayed above all fields. File "/local/User/demo/web/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in non_field_errors
  283.         return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class()) File "/local/User/demo/web/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  154.             self.full_clean() File "/local/User/demo/web/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  353.         self._clean_fields() File "/local/User/demo/web/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  362.             value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name)) File "/local/User/demo/web/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
  585.         return data.get(name, None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /Lcloud/ Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form's `__init__()` as follows:

```
def __init__(self, testList, args,**kwargs):
    self.testList = testList
    super(TestSubmitForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)  # testList not in args!
    # ...
```

The issue is that the `__init__()` of `forms.Form` (which you call via `super(...)`) expects a `dict`-like object as its first positional argument. Typically, if provided, that will be a `QueryDict` instance like `request.POST` or sth. similar.